# Dynamic Update Statement with only the columns that have updated values

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I need to execute an update statement, and I am not sure of the columns to be updated until an http patch request is sent. I need to modify employee records and I need to construct an update statement with only the columns that have updated values.

The table has columns employeerecords(ID,name,dateOfBirth,startyear,endyear,company).
and an example response of:

```
{
"name":"Jim"
}
```

Update: I am providing the ID by an URI parameter when the patch request is being sent. I am also implementing in Mule 4. I am not sure how to complete the following.

UPDATE employeerecord
SET -unknown-
WHERE ID =:ID;

Comment: Generally speaking an application should always provide _all_ of the field values to the back end - the complete record - not just the changed values. In your example, the data doesn't even include the key field of the record: how would you even know _which_ record to update, let alone what values to set things to... This is not a good design.

Comment: @pmdba, I have provided more information above. I am providing the PK by a URI parameter.

Comment: It is still not a good design. The API should accept all parameters - a complete record - as input and issue a single pre-determined update statement. Alternatively, different API calls could accept a specific subset of fields as input, but the SQL should still be static, not dynamic. Building dynamic SQL for DML commands is a recipe for SQL injection or other problems.

Comment: I agree with @pmdba here. Technically speaking you can test every single column once you receive the request and than from there build a dynamic sql that would  include the columns that you are trying to update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use dynamic SQL to solve this issue.  Assuming that you are using an Oracle version which supports `JSON_TABLE`, the following query should suffice:

```sql
UPDATE employee e
SET (name, dateofbirth, startyear, endyear, company) =
    (SELECT NVL(j.name, e.name), NVL(j.dateofBirth, e.dateofBirth),
            NVL(j.startyear, e.startyear), NVL(j.endyear, e.endyear),
            NVL(j.company, e.company)
     FROM JSON_TABLE('{"name":"Jim"}' --REPLACE WITH ACTUAL REQUEST
                      COLUMNS(name, dateOfBirth DATE, startyear, endyear, company)) j)
WHERE e.id = 1; --REPLACE WITH ACTUAL ID
```

Preferably, I would use bind variables as part of a procedure instead of hard coding the JSON and ID.

I've created a DBFiddle to show the query's effectiveness: ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=646ab18690d0128cd15223e8121afee4))

****EDIT 1: Added `NULL` CHECKING****

As was pointed out in the comments, my original query doesn't work if the user passes `NULL` in for a value in the request.  I have modified my query to work using the `EXISTS` functionality:

```sql
UPDATE employee e
SET (name, dateofbirth, startyear, endyear, company) =
    (SELECT DECODE(j.name_chk, 1, j.name, e.name), 
            DECODE(j.dob_chk, 1, j.dateofbirth, e.dateofBirth),
            DECODE(j.start_chk, 1, j.startyear, e.startyear),
            DECODE(j.end_chk, 1, j.endyear, e.endyear),
            DECODE(j.co_chk, 1, j.company, e.company)
     FROM JSON_TABLE('{"name":"Jim","endyear":null}' 
                      COLUMNS(name, name_chk NUMBER EXISTS PATH '$.name', 
                              dateOfBirth DATE, dob_chk NUMBER EXISTS PATH '$.dateofbirth',
                              startyear, start_chk NUMBER EXISTS PATH '$.startyear',
                              endyear, end_chk NUMBER EXISTS PATH '$.endyear',
                              company, co_chk NUMBER EXISTS PATH '$.company')) j)
WHERE e.id = 1;
```

I updated the DBFiddle as well ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=813de67007695926e0722d5f384ef5c2))

Comment: This method wouldn't work if the user calling the API wanted to set one of the columns to a null value. For example, a body with the request of `{"name":"Jim","endyear":null}` would not set the `endyear` column to null, it would keep the old value.

Comment: @EJEgyed Thank you for your comment.  You were absolutely right.  I added some functionality to check for an explicit `NULL`.